# Need help creating a single Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores the names of people in a users circle.
Relevant fields are: username  &  circleMember

I have another table that that stores all listings create by individual users.

My app sends a request to the server providing the active users username.

I need a query that will SELECT from circle circleMember WHERE username = ?username and then SELECT from listings * WHERE username = (the result of first query) the username, circleMember combinations are stored on individual rows so there will be multiple rows for each username.

```
table circle
 - circleId (int)
 - username (varchar) 
 - circleMember (varChar)

table listings
- listingId (int)
- username (varchar) 
- image (varchar) 
- title (varchar) 
- price (decimal 15,2) 
- description (varchar) 
- location(varchar)
```

My current script gets all listings from the database and presents them in Card Views. The result I am looking for is that a user will only see listings from usernames in their circle.

I have tried various combinations of single queries from posts on this site but apparently lack the proper syntax to make it work. Can this be done in a single query or do I need one to get results and then another to iterate through the results?

Comment: Help us help you - please post your table structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: what is a `circleMember`? a boolean, integer, string?

Comment: Keywords for your research: Sub-select, JOIN

Comment: Updated question with details on the field types. And description of what I need the query or queries to return.

Comment: This is a simple `JOIN` that is learned at basic MySQL levels... I'd recommend revisiting MySQL tutorials before you go much farther trying to develop apps within a database environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT * FROM listings
JOIN circle ON circle.circleMember = listings.username 
WHERE circle.username = "my_user_name"
```

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much for your help. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

So I think you want a simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM circle 
JOIN listings ON circle.username = listings.username 
WHERE circle.circleId = (SELECT circleId FROM circle WHERE username = <username> limit 1)
```

Where `<username>` is replaced with some quoted string.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

*no clue what 'circle circleMember is supposed to be*

Comment: I edited question with table details hopefully that will help!

Comment: @SkynetHasYou Still not clear to me. If this answer isn't helpful I can delete it.

Comment: Your code is returning all the listing created by the active user what I need is code that returns all the listings created by the active users "circleMembers"

Comment: Update still returns the active users listings and no other.